# angularx social login session

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I setup a google login for users using the **@abacritt/angularx-social-login** from here: **https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login**. My Problem is that whenever I refresh the page, the session apparently expires and I need to login again using my google account.

my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    QueryCreateComponent,
    FillFormDetailComponent,
    SendFormDetailComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    SocialLoginModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: true,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              'CLIENTID', googleLoginOptions
            )
          },
       
        ],
        onError: (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my login.component.ts where I tried to set the id_token from the google response in the local storage of my browser but with no effect.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{

  public user : SocialUser | undefined;
  private loggedIn: any;
  private accessToken : any;

  constructor(private authService: SocialAuthService, 
              private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }

 async ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.loggedIn = (user != null);
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', user.idToken);

      if (this.loggedIn) {
        this.userService.setCurrentUser(user);
        console.log("User set in LoginComponent:", user);
        // Redirect to QueryCreateComponent
        this.router.navigate(['/query']);
      }

    });
  }
}
```

What is the usual way of keeping a client side user session even when I refresh the page?

Comment: Did you find a way to resolve the problem? I have the same question

Comment: Its apparently a bug and you need to setup your own oAuth... I went with keycloak instead.